# Implement generic protocol which already has a default implementation?

Tags: ios, swift, generics, protocols, implementation

I have the following code and it works:

```
import Foundation
import RealmSwift

protocol GetAllDBServiceProtocol {
    associatedtype T: Object
    func getall() -> [T]
}

extension GetAllDBServiceProtocol {
    func getAll() -> [T] {
        DBStorageService().fetch(by: T.self)
    }
}

class DBStorageService {
    private let storage: Realm?
        
    init(
        _ configuration: Realm.Configuration = Realm.Configuration()
    ) {
        self.storage = try? Realm(configuration: configuration)
    }

    func fetch<T: Object>(by type: T.Type) -> [T] {
        guard let storage else { return [] }
        return storage.objects(T.self).toArray()
    }
}
```

Note: maybe it is incorrect to use `RealmSwift` via this way but it is not linked with the problem.

Now I want to add a service which returns a concrete realm object array:

```
class SomeDBService {
    private let storage: DBStorageService
    
    init(storage: DBStorageService) {
        self.storage = storage
    }
}

extension SomeDBService: GetAllDBServiceProtocol {
    func getall() -> [SomeDBEntity] {
        DBStorageService().fetch(by: SomeDBEntity.self)
    }
}
```

This works too but the problem is I can't access the default implementation of `GetAllDBServiceProtocol` - it becomes extra and can be safety removed.

So is it possible to make `SomeDBService` using default `GetAllDBServiceProtocol` implementation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 problems with your code. Firstly, the method name of the default protocol implementation has a typo in it - `getall` vs `getAll`, which means you don't actually provide a default implementation.

Secondly, when conforming to the protocol with the default implementation, you should simply define the `associatedType` via a `typealias` without declaring the `getAll` method.

Here's a simplified working example that doesn't rely on Realm (adding back the `Object` type constraints will still work fine, I've just removed it to make the code compilable without needing Realm):

```
protocol GetAllDBServiceProtocol {
    associatedtype Model
    func getAll() -> [Model]
}

extension GetAllDBServiceProtocol {
    func getAll() -> [Model] {
        DBStorageService().fetch(by: Model.self)
    }
}

class DBStorageService {
    func fetch<T>(by type: T.Type) -> [T] {
        []
    }
}

class SomeDBService {
    private let storage: DBStorageService

    init(storage: DBStorageService) {
        self.storage = storage
    }
}

extension SomeDBService: GetAllDBServiceProtocol {
    typealias Model = Int
}
```

Comment: Thanks, the problem was with `getall`/`getAll`. No `typealias` is not an error by itself because it is used to specify type but in some cases you can just write methods implementation with concrete types. It is redundant to use both of them simultaneously